# Joining tables on dates, but aligning one table by an extra day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have two tables below:

### table A

```
+------------+-------+
|    Date    | Value |
+------------+-------+
| 11-08-2018 |   2.3 |
| 11-09-2018 |   4.3 |
| 11-12-2018 |   2.9 |
| 11-13-2018 |   3.9 |
+------------+-------+
```

### table B

```
+------------+---------+
|    Date    |  Value  |
+------------+---------+
| 11-07-2018 |   -6.99 |
| 11-08-2018 | 12.3333 |
| 11-09-2018 |   14.22 |
| 11-12-2018 |    3.66 |
+------------+---------+
```

I need to join them on the Date field however I want to join them so I get a result like below (i.e. I want to add a day to the date field in table B also ignoring weekend)

```
+------------+---------+---------+
|    Date    | Value A | Value B |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 11-08-2018 |     2.3 |   -6.99 |
| 11-09-2018 |     4.3 |  12.333 |
| 11-12-2018 |     2.9 |   14.22 |
| 11-13-2018 |     3.9 |    3.66 |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

How best to achieve this?

Comment: ..JOIN ON TableA.date = dateadd(day,1,TableB.date)... this may confound the use of indexs, if applicable, but in the case of poor performance, there would be ways of mitigating that

Comment: would weekends though cause this to not work?

Comment: yes sorry, you need the more complex arrangement suggested below by SalmanA, i missed that part, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to join Monday with previous Friday:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea
INNER JOIN tableb ON DATEADD(DAY, IIF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, tablea.Date) = 'Monday', -3, -1), tablea.Date) = tableb.Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function that adds days to a date skipping the weekend days:

```
create function dbo.udf_AddWorkingDays(@dateToIncrement as date, @daysToAdd as int)
returns datetime
as
begin
    SET @dateToIncrement = dateadd(d, @daysToAdd, @dateToIncrement)

    --skip sundays
    IF datename(DW, @dateToIncrement) = 'sunday'   
        SET @dateToIncrement = dateadd(d, 1, @dateToIncrement)

    --skip saturdays
    IF datename(DW, @dateToIncrement) = 'saturday' 
        SET @dateToIncrement = dateadd(d, 2, @dateToIncrement)

    return cast(@dateToIncrement AS datetime)
end
```

Use the functions in your join condition:

```
declare  @tableA table ([Date] date , [Value] decimal(10,2))
declare  @tableB table ([Date] date , [Value] decimal(10,2))
insert into @tableA values
 ('2018-11-08', 2.3)
,('2018-11-09', 4.3)
,('2018-11-12', 2.9)
,('2018-11-13', 3.9)

insert into @tableB values
 ('2018-11-07', -6.99  )
,('2018-11-08', 12.3333)
,('2018-11-09', 14.22  )
,('2018-11-12', 3.66   )

select A.[Date], A.[Value], B.[Value]
from @tableA A
inner join @tableB B on A.[Date] = dbo.udf_AddWorkingDays(B.[Date], 1)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your join condition accordingly

```
SELECT TableA.Date, TableA.Value as [Value A], TableB.Value as [Value B]
FROM TableB
JOIN TableA
ON TableA.Date = DATEADD(day, 1, TableA.Date)
```

Comment: I don't think this would work for Fridays as it would then become saturday and I'm working on a 5 day calendar